# Replace PHP with Python with Apache

Tags: php, python, apache, mod-wsgi

Basically I'm looking for a way to get rid of my PHP dependence, and I would like to switch to Python.  I'm having trouble finding a way to basically make python a drop in replacement.  I'm familiar with Django but its just not quick and dirty enough for most small things I have to do.  So I'm wondering if there is an Apache module or a way to setup mod_wsgi to serve up *.py files the same way mod_php serves up *.php from the server root?

Note: I have found the various python extensions to php for calling code from PHP but that doesn't really solve the curly brace hell.

Comment: Python and PHP simply are two different beasts, it not just a matter of different syntax. Either you make the jump or you don't. :)

Comment: Nothing solves curly brace hell except banishment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The files that mod_wsgi calls *are* Python files.  Additionally, if you set them up in daemon mode, updating the python file will restart the daemon.  It's pretty slick.

Another thing you could look at if Django is overkill is [Werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/), which is pretty much just the server interface.  Then later you can add database access with [SqlAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) and/or templating with [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).  Or not.

These pieces are pretty much what people use when they want Django as pieces, and I'm told that they're more powerful, if more work to maintain (some assembly required).

Comment: I understand that mod_wsgi calls python files, but is there a way for it to drill down dir/file wise in the doc root like HTML/PHP is handled or would I just have to write a delegating script to always be called by mod_wsgi and have it delegate which script to call?

Comment: The latter. One of the *features* of WSGI is that the Python code is not exposed on the server. Typically you have another path set up on the server for static content, rather than mixing it in with the code.

Comment: I like your answer the most because you pointed me in the right direction, namely not completely reinventing the wheel.  Though after looking into Werkzeug, I found a seemingly even more barebone approach called web.py: http://webpy.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that with mod_wsgi, but if you are new to developing Python web applications it is a potentially painful way to go about it. Either way, read the documentation at:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive

You use AddHander just like you would with CGI or PHP scripts.

Answer (score 0):

if you worked with php also you are familiar to mod_php

also there is mod_python ( http://www.modpython.org/ ) but its not active community ( there is many article how set django with mod_python ( http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modpython/ ) )

but its better use wsgi and uwsgi

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/modwsgi/
- http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/

Comment: The mod_python project has no active community because it is officially dead and the Apache software foundation has sent it off to the Attic.

Comment: @ graham Dumpleton: yes true ;)

Comment: mod_python works differently than mod_php:
http://docs.python.org/howto/webservers.html#mod-python

Comment: yes but for php developers its easier than uwsgi and others ;)